# Permissions denied when writing to symlink

Tags: php, linux, centos, centos7

I have a program that is being hosted on a linux box running Centos 7. The program is accepting form data and saving to a windows file server. the windows file server is mounted on the linux box. i have created a symlink in the directory that the program is in. everytime that i launch the program in the web browser and try and add the data, i receive the following error:

> file_put_contents(/W/Shortage/2017/Apr/Shortage04-04-17.csv): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/DriverTest/driverss.php on line 78

In my smb.conf file, i have the property already set to follow symlinks. everyone has rwx rights to the files and the symlinks as well. this is the php code where the error is referring to:

```
if(!is_dir('/W/Shortage/'.$year. '/' .$month))
    {
        mkdir('/W/Shortage/'.$year. '/' .$month, 0777, true);
    }
file_put_contents('/W/Shortage/'.$year. '/' .$month. '/Shortage'.date('m-d-y').".csv", $result, FILE_APPEND);
```

when i SSH into the system using a user that i created, i can cd into the directory and do `touch test.txt` and the file is created. i can also use vi to edit the test.txt file and enter data into it. in the directory, the owner of the files and folders are apache. i am not sure why i do not have any permissions to write to that directory. any suggestions or anyone seeing anything wrong with what i am doing so far?

Comment: The access by your web server might be denied on account of applicable SELinux security policy.  You can test that possibility by temporarily putting the machine into permissive mode via the `setenforce` command, and trying again.  It might also be denied on the Windows side.  Your mount options and SMB configuration cannot unilaterally grant access that the file server itself denies.

Comment: Ok, i can try the `setenforce` command. i have not used this command before, so the command would be: `setenforce permissive`? Edit: i just ran the command `setenforce permissive` ran my code, and that worked! What happens if this linux box is restarted? would i have to run this `setenforce permissive` command all of the time?

Comment: Either `setenforce Permissive` or `setenforce 0` will put the machine into permissive mode.  You'll need to do that with privilege, so either as root or via `sudo`.

Comment: is this a permanent fix, or would i have to run this command each time that the linux box gets restarted?

Comment: **NO!** This is a troubleshooting step only, as it disables ALL protection from SELinux. You'll likely need to do something like `chcon -Rt httpd_sys_rw_content_t /W/Shortage` to change the context of the relevant directory. Using a tool like `audit2why` and `audit2allow` will help out.

Comment: Ok, good to know. when i try something like `chcon -Rr httpd_sys_rw_content_t /W` i receive an error message saying failed to change context of /W to system object: Operation no supported.

Comment: Probably because it's not XFS or EXT4 filesystem. Your options may be limited by having a remote drive.

Comment: It's odd that you can create the directory though; what does `ls -l` look like for the newly created directory? And you did mean `chcon -Rt ...` in your comment, right?

Comment: If indeed it is an SELinux issue, then the best available fixes are to either label the file in a way that permits access, or to add a local policy module that permits the desired access.  If you cannot do the former then it might be difficult to do the latter without seriously compromising system security.  You might then consider reversing the hosting arrangement by keeping the file on Linux and exporting a CIFS / SMB share containing it to the Windows side.

Comment: @miken32 when i ran the command `df -T` i found that my file system for my mount point is tmpfs. i just used the mount command `mount -o`, and of course added in my necessary information for the mount point. after doing some research, the way i used the mount command would have created the mounting share as an XFS rather than tmpfs.  when i run `ls -l` on the newly created directory, i receive: total 1 -rwxrwxrwx. 1 apache apache 253 Apr 4 16:27 Shortage04-04-17.csv   Also yes, i mistyped the chcon. you are correct on that one

Comment: @JohnBollinger i will look into adding a local policy module using audit2allow. the only problem with your second suggestion is that i don't have full access rights to the Windows file server, so i may not be able to export a SMB share.

Comment: hi , I had a same problem... Permission denied ... and I couldn't create a symlink.... and I solved it with chmod 777 for folder and subfolder... h